# Show icons on dropdown menu android

Tags: android, menu

First of all, sorry for my bad english, I'm trying my best for this question.

**This is my problem:**
I'm doing an app about drawing, and I'm trying to show icons on the drop down menu, instead of the title, but I am not able to show the icon.

I have tried this:

```
 <item android:id="@+id/pickColor" android:title="@string/pickColor"
    android:icon="@drawable/colors"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

and this shows me the icon in the ActionBar.

However if I change the parameter `app:showAsAction="always"` 
to this `app:showAsAction="never"` the app shows the title from that menu item.

So my problem it's that I want to show a dropdown menu but only with icons instead of the default titles.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this post:

- http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html

Or this tutorial:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Comment: Thanks I will use the custom spinner